# Q: Will fined beer re-settle if disturbed?

Tags: finings, gelatin

I've successfully fined my last several batches using gelatin, added while the beer is still at room temperature, then promptly refrigerated. I fill two half-barrel (48 l) Sankey kegs at a time, and use a chain hoist to lower them into the kegerator.

Now that it's cold outside (freezing rain here, in fact), I'm wondering if I could get ahead by fining and kegging another couple of batches and chilling them in Nature's own refrigerator. But transferring them to the kegerator would inevitably disturb the sediment, so I'm wondering if anyone knows whether or not fined beer re-settles quickly, slowly, or not at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience beer fined with gelatin when disturbed does settle out again but seems to take longer than the original fining time.  May take weeks if it's already carbonated.

I "think" the reason is that the disturbed particles grab some cO2 and become slightly buoyant.

Comment: Thanks, Evil Zymurgist. A power failure caused by the worst ice storm in decades forced me to conduct an impromptu experiment: fining & kegging, then leaving the kegs outside for 2 days, and finally lugging them back to the kegerator. After 2 more days of settling, my results would tend to confirm your experience: clearer than unfined beer, but not as quick to settle the second time around.